# supersized plugin on ajax page

Tags: jquery, destroy, supersized

I need to use supersized plugin on my ajax page. But i think there's no any destroy  function for supersized. How can i set supersized again when i call my function below?

**Solution:**

```
if($.supersized.vars.slideshow_interval){
   clearInterval($.supersized.vars.slideshow_interval);
};
```

just add this to supersized gallery close button...

```
function getSuperSized(arr,startSlide){
      $(".myPageHolder").hide();
      $("body").append("<div class='supersizedHolder'></div>");
      $("#supersized-loader").remove();
      $("#supersized").remove();
      $(".supersizedHolder").append("<div id='supersized-loader'></div><ul id='supersized'></ul>")
      $("#supersized-loader").show();
      $("#supersized").show();
      var innerContent= supersized elements goes here...
      $(".supersizedHolder").append(innerContent);

      $(".closeSupersized") /*remove supersized holder and back to page*/
      .click(function(){
              /*solution*/
              if($.supersized.vars.slideshow_interval){
                  clearInterval($.supersized.vars.slideshow_interval);
              };
              //
          $(".myPageHolder").show();
          $(".supersizedHolder").remove();
      });

      var superSizedImages=[];
      for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
          var img=pageUrl+"assets/content/large/"+arr[i].media.content[0].media
          superSizedImages.push({image : img, title : '', thumb : '', url : ''})
      };

      $.supersized({
            options goes here....
      });
};
```

Comment: Could you please post your solution as an answer and accept it, instead of putting it in the question?

Answer (score 0):

This message is to remove the question from the Unanswered list.

Is already solved in the main question through multiple editions.